# How to avoid re-binding data controls with ASP.Net Dynamically Loading a User Control

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, user-controls

The overall problem is that I have a web application that has many hidden controls that are shown and hidden based on user rights or based on particular actions within the main page.  Because there are so many hidden controls and the combination of each of these control's databinds paired with the sheer size of the resulting rendered HTML, the page is too slow to load.  We can of course move the databinds to only occur on the show of the controls but this only addresses half of the problem.  We are attempting to address both by Dynamically loading the usercontrols.  As we all know the problem with this approach is that when dynamically loading the control, it must be re-added to the page on every subsequent request.  So anytime say a dropdown in selected on the dynamic child control that causes an action (like OnClick event), it has to reload the child control, which by itself isn't bad but you also have to rebind all the controls on the page or your databound controls will all be empty.  So is there anyway to get around having to rebind all of the controls with every load of the child control?  I know that for simple things like a textbox I could save the viewstate and the text would persist between requests and reloading the control, but say the child control has a grid with several hundred rows of data after it is bound, how do I persist that when reloading the child control?  I can post a small example if needed.

Answer (score 0):

use Update Panel, i think i will call to server only for updated data not whole page or control.